# Var and Hoisting

Tags: javascript

1. My First Question: javascript takes declarations and put on the top
   of function code because of hoisting before any code executed, i
   want to know that in this situation which i stated below there is
   two variables declared they are written like this var a, a;? because
   of hoisting on the top of function code ? if like that why i am not
   accessing second variable a before initilization why i am accessing
   first variable a after initilization, In short on line 4 of function
   code console.log(a) // 10 how javascript decide to give 10 and not
   undefined, Note that there is two variables declare with same name
   on top.
2. My Second Question: it is possible when javascript scan the code and
   find 2 variables with same name and it remove one variable and used
   another in the code execution.

   ```js
   function myFunc() {
     console.log(a);
     var a = 10;
     console.log(a);
     var a = 20;
     console.log(a);

   }

   myFunc();
   ```

Comment: If you want to treat these as an error, placing `"use strict";` at top of code should treat duplicate declarations and failure to declare variables as errors. Link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1: "Are two variables declared when written like this:**

```
 var a, a;
```

**Answer 1: No.**

JavaScript source code is scanned before execution and in [sloppy mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode), any number of declarations of the same identifier ('`a`' in this case) as a variable **using the `var` keyword** are amalgamated and hoisted as a *single variable declaration* at the top of the function (or script element in the case of top level variables in a script file or inline  element).

Named functions declared with the `function` keyword are also hoisted to the top of an enclosing function or script element with some differences:

- Hoisted functions are compiled when hoisted and can be called before they appear in source.
- Declaring a function with the same name as a previous function declared in the same scope replaces the previous declaration. Only code for the last same-named function in the same scope will be hoisted.

---

**Question 2** Is it possible that when the Javascript engine scans the code and find 2 variables with same name, it removes one variable and uses the other in the code execution?

**Answer 2: Yes**

To restate it slightly, the JavaScript engine **does not find** two variables, it finds two **variable declarations** which when hoisted only result in a single binding of the variable name to where it is stored in memory - meaning only one variable is created.

Answer (score 0):

- `var` declarations are hoisted to the top of the function.
- Duplicate declarations have no effect.
- `var` declarations are handled separately from assignments.

You code is essentially the same as:

```
function myFunc() {
  var a; // Declaration is hoisted
  console.log(a);
  a = 10; // Assignment is not
  console.log(a);
  a = 20; // Second assignment is also not
  console.log(a);
}
```

---

`var` is distinctly unintuitive which is why modern code avoids it in favour of `const` and, occasionally, `let`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what happens here is when you are declaring `var`, a hoisting will be done. By default, `a` would be initialized with `undefined` during hoisting.

So, basically the variable `a` is declared only one time, not two times, only the initialization is done multiple times. Here `a` would be declared first and then when we come to the line 4 where it is initialized. It gets a value 10, and again, when it gets to line 6 its value would be replaced/changed by 20.

So basically we can imagine that when hoisting is done, a place named the in the memory is given and when we initialize, it gets a value placed in it.